# Ignore x-label alignment with multiple plots in patchwork: is this possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, patchwork

I really like the patchwork package, alignment of multiple plots is often better and easier to realize than in other packages (cowplot/gridextra).

However, one thing I cannot solve: Is it possible to ignore x-axis alignment in a patchwork, and only align all other elements? Or to adjust this x-axis alignment afterwords in the patchwork manually? 
See attached figure: I want the x-axis title from patch B and C (Petal.Length) closer to the x-axis, if possible.

[image]

Code that produced the image:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plot.1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("A very\nvery\nlong\nlabel", "","")) +
  labs(x = element_blank())

plot.2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()

(plot.1 |plot.2)/(plot.2|plot.1) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")
```

Comment: One of the comments by the package author in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/110) indicates this may not be possible.  But hopefully someone will come along with a workaround!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I did not notice that issue yet! I hope someone can find a workaround. This can probably be solved with the cowplot plot_grid function, but my actual plot is more complicated and I had other issues with the cowplot package unfortunately: https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/31#issuecomment-389193848

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### OP example

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plot.1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("A very\nvery\nlong\nlabel", "","")) +
  labs(x = element_blank())

plot.2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()

(plot.1 | plot.2) / 
  (plot.2 | plot.1) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")
```

[image: reshow OP figure]

### Use negative margins

It took me a while to realize that the issue derives from
the need to align a mixture of `axis.text`s and `axis.title`s.
Even though they are grammatically different elements,
the categorical axis text serves most or all
of the practical function that the continuous axis title does.
Titles will always be grid-aligned outside of the aligned text region.
Justification alone can't solve that problem, but negative margins can.

Notes:

- The negative margin value you will want depends on other scaling factors in the plot, so this is one of those *polish at the very end* solutions. `-50` worked in this case, but I've needed to use other values
- It also works for y-axis
- I messed around with parentheses but otherwise the plot spec is identical other than the extra `theme()` layer
- You normally will not want to include this negative margin theme snippet in the individual plot definition, because it will appear to *cause* a bug there and you won't be able to iteratively refine the margin value that way, at least not easily if your script/Rmd is long and/or complex. This really is an issue only at the level of assembling the plots with `patchwork`, so it is probably best practice to keep a polishing tweak like this where you're defining the patchwork assembly, as I've shown here.

```r
(plot.1 | (
  plot.2 +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -50, unit = "pt"))))
) / (
  (plot.2 +
     theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -50, unit = "pt")))) | 
    plot.1
) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")
```

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem with y-axis labels, and this solution worked perfectly. Please note the `theme()` code becomes `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = -50, unit = "pt")))` -- you have to reduce the right-side margin with the `r` parameter of `margin()` rather than the top-side margin with `t`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack. If you use the function patchwork::patchworkGrob, the plots will be stored in a gtable that can be edited. You just have to find the right layout values in the table. Every layout part has 't r l b' dimensions that you can edit (I believe top, right, left, bottom). In my case, I want to change the bottom value of "xlab-b".  After changing the values, the gtable can be plotted with grid::grid.draw(). If needed y-axis position can be changed in a similar manner In a similar manner (ylab-l).

```
library(grid) # should be loaded already, just to be sure.

# Unadjusted patchwork:
plots <- (plot.1 |plot.2)/(plot.2|plot.1) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")

# create gTable object
plots.gtable <- patchworkGrob(plots)

# edit gtable object:
# tables are found in the list ‘plots.gtable$grobs’
# Second and fourth grobs in the list are the TableGrobs to edit:
# First edit panel B:
plots.gtable$grobs[[2]]$layout[
  plots.gtable$grobs[[2]]$layout$name == "xlab-b",
  ]$b[2] <- 12 # change this number, for me 12 worked fine
# Ends with $b[2] because we only want to adjust position of 
# the x-axis title of panel B.
# To adjust the position of the x-axis title of both plot A and B, 
# just leave out the [2].

# Now access lower two patchwork TableGrobs:
# edit panel C:
plots.gtable$grobs[[4]]$layout[
  plots.gtable$grobs[[4]]$layout$name == "xlab-b",
  ]$b[1] <- 12

# plot the adjusted figure:
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(plots.gtable)
```

[edited-patchwork-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7YMt.png)

edit 29-01-2021: I think the recent answer from [Paul McMurdie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946462/11856430) is easier than the one I mention here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by [Paul 'Joey' McMurdie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946462/11307789) works great!

I am adding here alternative, which might be useful in case of complex nesting where you want to target only a single plot.

So for example:

```
plot.1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("A very\nvery\nlong\nlabel", "","")) +
  labs(x = element_blank())

plot.2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()

fig <- 
  (plot.1 |plot.2)/(plot.2|plot.1) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")

fig[[1]][[2]] <- fig[[1]][[2]] + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 12))
fig
```

Will produce following, where only a single plot was modified:

[image: plot]